# How to pass the id of the selected CommandLink

Tags: java, jsf, commandlink

I have a datatable, and one of the columns contains the status of the particular item. The status appears as a commandLink in the column. If the status of the item as retrieved from the database is a comma separated value like Status1,Status 2, I have to display 2 commandlinks in the column for the same item namely, one with Status1 and another with Status 2.

```
<h:commandLink id="status1Link" value="#{pc_test.status1}"
                            onclick="showAssignKeyRvPopup(#{plist.t3Id},'#{plist.t3FileName}','#{plist.status}');return false;"
                            rendered="#{plist.status == 'Status1,Status2'}"
                            update="assignKeyRvDialog">
                        </h:commandLink>
```

The above is the code I'm using to display the commandLink. on click, it shows a popup, from which if I clcik OK, I have to perform an action that updates the status again. I have 2 commandLinks in the same column, my question is when I click on one commandLink and perform an action, I want the text of that commandLink only to change, not the other one. So, I need to pass the id of the commandLink that I click. Please let me know how I can go about doing this.

I tried just as you suggested -

```
<p:remoteCommand name="doSubmit" actionListener="#{pc_testmaps.doAssignUser}" />

<p:commandButton id="assignUser" value="Submit" onclick="doSubmit();"> </p:commandButton>

function doSubmit() {
            document.getElementById('nonMCLink') = commandLinkId;
            doAssignUser([{name:'commandLinkId', value:commandLinkId}]);
        }

And in the bean, 

public void doAssignUser() throws DelegateException {

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map<String, String> map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        String linkStatus = (String) map.get("commandLinkId");
        System.out.println(linkStatus);
}
```

It still doesn't seem to work, when I print the linkStatus value, I'm getting it as null. Please help.

Comment: do you use 3rd component technology like primefaces,richfaces..

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Primefaces 3.0

Comment: Your concrete functional requirement is unclear. *"I want the text of that commandLink only to change, not the other one"* Before or after invoking the method? If before, why don't you just use onclick? If after, why don't you just modify `#{pc_test.status1}`? By the way, please don't obfuscate PrimeFaces away if you were actually using it. It would only lead to more confusion and possibly inapplicable answers. The `update` attribute is invalid in `<h:commandLink>` and the `<p:commandLink>` has more enhanced attributes which could be used to solve the problem more easily.

Comment: Sorry I have not been clear. I would like the status to change after invoking the method, and I would want to know which of the 2 command links I have clicked so that I can update the appropriate link's status.

Answer (score 1):

if you use primefaces,it can be so easily with 
[p:remoteCommand](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/remoteCommand.jsf)

Firstly,get id of `commandLink` using javascript,then you can get it into your bean using action.

Here is simple example.Check this out.

[using remoteCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908693/primefaces-remotecommand-tag-is-not-working-when-passing-html-of-my-current-page/12922502#12922502)

**UPDATE**

```
    <p:remoteCommand name="doSubmit"
        actionListener="#{yourBean.doSubmit}" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function onOKclick() {
$(document).ready(function() {
    var commandLinkID = "yourcommandlinkId" //or get id using javascript with name          
doSubmit([{name:'commandLinkID', value:commandLinkID}]);
    });         
}
</script>
```

Your OK buton on the popup

```
  <h:commandButton onclick="onOKclick();" /> 
//calling onOKclick js function is important.you can call onOkclikc js function where you want
```

Your doSubmitMethod in your bean;

```
public void doSubmit(){
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            Map<String, String> map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
           String value = (String) map.get("commandLinkID");
System.out.print(value);


}
```

Maybe it helps is you.

Comment: I have 2 commandLinks in the same column as I mentioned, and when I click on either, it shows a popup from where I can select a user. Only when I click on OK in that popup, does the doSubmit method in the bean get called. So, in this case, if I have a javascript function, where do I call it from? Also please tell me if there's any other way to do this.

Comment: ok when you click on OK in your popup,you can call javascript and passing id of commandLink which you want

Comment: I have edited my question after trying out the ideas you gave, please take a look.